# Slack webhook - Getting: "The request could not be satisfied." - Ruby

Tags: ruby, post, scripting, slack

Im was trying to post a message in Slack through POST request.
But I was getting 400 Bad Request, The request could not be satisfied.

My POST request was:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXYXXXYX/YYYXXXYYY/21slaajsajslkk212ks")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

header = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
params = { text: changelog_diff }
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
request.body = params.to_json

http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 3):

So the problem was that I didn't setting Net::http to use ssl.
Just add this line:

```
http.use_ssl = true
```

and require 'openssl' at the beginning.

So:

```
require 'net/http'        
require 'uri'        
require 'openssl'    

uri =    
URI.parse('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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')        
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = true            

header = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }        
params = { text: 'Some text to post' }        
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)        
request.body = params.to_json        

http.request(request)
```

Hope that helps you!